# How to install properly CocoaPods on Macbook M1 Silicon

Tags: macos, cocoapods, homebrew, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I am trying to install Cocoa Pods on my new MacBook Pro with the M1 Chip.

There are some solutions that found from December. Since is February those solutions may be a little outdated.

I cannot find any instructions on CocoaPods website. Would anyone be able to help me with that matter? I want to do it right and, sadly, I have little knowledge about that topic.

Many thanks for help.

Comment: For me was the solution through the Homebrew.

Answer (score 16):

These are the steps I followed :

Install HomeBrew in M1 Mac, open the Rosetta Terminal and run the following command :

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

After Homebrew installation is done, run this command in the terminal :

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Comment: It works for me on Air M1 2020, Thanks!

Comment: This seems to works with command arch -arm64 brew install cocoapods, only solution that worked

Comment: OutStanding working for me.............M1 pro

Answer (score 5):

I have mac Pro M1, Try to run on x86_64 architecture:

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

Then at the root of your project

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Answer (score 4):

For me was the solution through the Homebrew.

1. Install Homebrew natively on M1
   https://docs.brew.sh/Installation#alternative-installs
2. Then install Cocoapods
   https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, you should have homebrew

```
arch -arm64 brew install cocoapods
```