# Cannot install pod using M1 chip

Tags: ios, ruby, macos, cocoapods, apple-m1

I am trying to install pod but every time I am getting following error. I tried to remove ruby, installation of cocoapods & homebrew but still is there.

Note: **I am using M1 chipset.**

```
dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/psych-4.0.3/lib/psych.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/psych-4.0.3/lib/psych.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/psych.bundle' (no such file) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/psych-4.0.3/lib/psych.bundle (LoadError)
```

[image]

Comment: I found this link. May be this will help you. Link<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66067437/how-to-install-properly-cocoapods-on-macbook-m1-silicon>?

Comment: [Check this, this might help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66067437/how-to-install-properly-cocoapods-on-macbook-m1-silicon)

Answer (score 1):

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Then follow the command

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

Go to your project path here we have to mention architecture.

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Thanks RedPanda0147